# c# What is the right way to get an RSA key with public exponent 3 from System.Security.Cryptography?

Tags: c#, exception, key, rsa, system.security

I have a c# program using System.Security.Cryptography (standard provider) that needs to generate RSA keys of a particular bit size and exponent to interface with another long standing system.  This code seems reasonable to me:

```
            for (int trix = 0; trix < 1000; trix++)
            {
                using (var rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024)) // public key length in bits
                { // PROBLEM: MS seems stuck on the big exponent
                    RSAParameters key2 = rsa2.ExportParameters(true);
                    key2.Exponent = new byte[1] { 3 }; // public key exponent
                    rsa2.ImportParameters(key2);
                    PrintToFeedback(rsa2.ToXmlString(true));
                    byte[] bm0 = Utilities.HexStringToByteArray("1002030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f");
                    byte[] bm1 = rsa2.Encrypt(bm0, false);
                    byte[] bm2 = rsa2.Decrypt(bm1, false);
                    string szbm0 = Utilities.ByteArrayToHexString(bm0);
                    string szbm2 = Utilities.ByteArrayToHexString(bm2);
                    if (szbm0 != szbm2)
                    {
                        PrintToFeedback("RSA module test FAILED with MS RSA keys with small exponent, bm0, bm1, bm2 follow:");
                        PrintToFeedback(szbm0);
                        PrintToFeedback(Utilities.ByteArrayToHexString(bm1));
                        PrintToFeedback(szbm2);
                        ok = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Most of the time but not always, I get a Bad Parameter exception on rsa2.ImportParameters with the 3 exponent.  Sometimes it works, and I have had runs where rsa2.ToXmlString shows an Exponent of 3:

```
<Exponent>Aw==</Exponent>

>base64 -d | xxd
Aw==
00000000: 03
```

The test loop sometimes fails with nonzero trix, so it works a little.  See the screenshot and [this MSDN social network post from 2019](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c428d1c-e890-4673-af57-3b988289eb9a/rsa-importparameters-is-generating-intermittent-the-parameter-is-incorrect-error-message-for)

What is the right way to get a 1024 bit key with exponent 3 from System.Security.Cryptography?

(edited to add MSDN link)

[image: screenshot of exception]

Comment: I can't find any indication in the documentation that the specification of the public exponent is supported. And simply exporting the parameters, changing the public exponent, and importing the parameters should generally result in inconsistent data. I would use BouncyCastle for this task. That library allows you to generate an RSA key, specifying size and public exponent.

Comment: @Topaco, thanks for that suggestion.  The program already uses a lot of 3DES and Hash code from .Net.  I think importing BouncyCastle or OpenSSL would force a big rewrite because there is some name collision between those libraries and System.Security.Cryptography.  I don't think the libraries can coexist.  On the data consistency, I imagine that the key must refresh itself with the new exponent.  In the few cases where there is no exception on ImportParameters, the encrypt-decrypt test works.

Comment: An analysis of a successfully generated key in an ASN.1 parser (e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/) shows that only the public exponent has been changed and the other params haven't been adjusted, so the data is generally inconsistent. An OpenSSL check (*openssl rsa -check -in <key>*) of this key returned an *RSA key error: d e not congruent to 1*, confirming this assumption. You can verify this yourself with the tools mentioned.

Comment: BouncyCastle is usually used in parallel with native .NET crypto implementations without any problems, but of course I can't say that for sure for your application since I don't know your application in detail. As for the rewrite, you can use BC exclusively for key generation. There is no reason to migrate the rest to BC.

Comment: Thanks, Topaco.  I will take a closer look at BC.  For the record, I put the test in a try block and recorded all the key values that did not cause exceptions with exponent 3.  Out of 100 tests, I got 26 keys.  Looping through those N,P,Q values with the exponent 65537, all but one passed an encrypt-decrypt test.  So maybe the problem is not "intermittent" as much as, "MS throws an exception on ImportParameters when the new exponent will not work with the old key values."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the public exponent, the remaining dependent components (namely `P`, `Q`, `Modulus`, `D`, `DP`, `DQ`, `InverseQ`) of the key must also be adjusted. To achieve this, it is definitely better to use specialized tools, e.g. BouncyCastle.

In pure C# you can do something like:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
    {
        RSAParameters key = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

        // new public exponent
        BigInteger e = 3;

        // update public exponent and adjust dependent components
        UpdatePublicExponent(ref key, e);
        
        rsa.ImportParameters(key);

        Console.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(true));
        byte[] bm0 =
            HexStringToByteArray(
                "1002030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f");
        byte[] bm1 = rsa.Encrypt(bm0, false);
        byte[] bm2 = rsa.Decrypt(bm1, false);

        Console.WriteLine(bm0.SequenceEqual(bm2));
    }
}
```

Here is `UpdatePublicExponent` with the other helper functions:

```cs
private static void UpdatePublicExponent(ref RSAParameters key, BigInteger e)
{
    int keyBytes = key.Modulus?.Length ?? 128;
    int keyBitLength = 8 * keyBytes;

    int pBitLength = (keyBitLength + 1) / 2;
    int qBitLength = keyBitLength - pBitLength;
    int minDiffBits = keyBitLength / 3;

    for (;;)
    {
        BigInteger p = GetRandomPrime(pBitLength, e);
        BigInteger q, n;
        for (;;)
        {
            q = GetRandomPrime(qBitLength, e);

            // p and q should not be too close together (or equal!)
            BigInteger diff = BigInteger.Abs(q - p);
            if (diff.GetBitLength() < minDiffBits)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // calculate the modulus
            n = p * q;

            if (n.GetBitLength() != keyBitLength)
            {
                // if we get here our primes aren't big enough, make the largest
                // of the two p and try again
                p = BigInteger.Max(p, q);
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        if (p < q)
        {
            BigInteger tmp = p;
            p = q;
            q = tmp;
        }

        BigInteger pSub1 = p - 1;
        BigInteger qSub1 = q - 1;

        BigInteger gcd = BigInteger.GreatestCommonDivisor(pSub1, qSub1);
        BigInteger lcm = pSub1 / gcd * qSub1;

        // calculate the private exponent
        BigInteger d = ModInverse(e, lcm);

        if (d.GetBitLength() <= qBitLength)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // calculate the CRT factors
        BigInteger dP = d % pSub1;
        BigInteger dQ = d % qSub1;
        BigInteger invQ = ModInverse(p, q);

        int halfBytes = (keyBytes + 1) / 2;

        // update key components
        key.P = GetBytes(p, halfBytes);
        key.Q = GetBytes(q, halfBytes);
        key.Modulus = GetBytes(n, keyBytes);

        key.Exponent = GetBytes(e, -1);

        key.D = GetBytes(d, keyBytes);
        key.DP = GetBytes(dP, halfBytes);
        key.DQ = GetBytes(dQ, halfBytes);
        key.InverseQ = GetBytes(invQ, halfBytes);

        break;
    }
}

private static BigInteger ModInverse(BigInteger a, BigInteger n)
{
    BigInteger i = n, v = 0, d = 1;
    while (a > 0)
    {
        BigInteger t = i / a, x = a;
        a = i % x;
        i = x;
        x = d;
        d = v - t * x;
        v = x;
    }
    v %= n;
    if (v < 0) v = (v + n) % n;
    return v;
}

private static BigInteger GetRandomPrime(int bitCount, BigInteger e)
{
    BigInteger prime;
    RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    int byteLength = (bitCount + 7) / 8;
    do
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteLength];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);
        prime = new BigInteger(bytes, true);
    } while (prime.GetBitLength() != bitCount || prime % e == BigInteger.One || !IsProbablePrime(prime, 40));

    rng.Dispose();
    return prime;
}

// Miller-Rabin primality test as an extension method on the BigInteger type.
// http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#C.23
private static bool IsProbablePrime(BigInteger source, int certainty)
{
    if (source == 2 || source == 3)
        return true;
    if (source < 2 || source % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    BigInteger d = source - 1;
    int s = 0;

    while (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        d /= 2;
        s += 1;
    }

    // There is no built-in method for generating random BigInteger values.
    // Instead, random BigIntegers are constructed from randomly generated
    // byte arrays of the same length as the source.
    RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[source.ToByteArray().LongLength];
    BigInteger a;

    for (int i = 0; i < certainty; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            // This may raise an exception in Mono 2.10.8 and earlier.
            // http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2761
            rng.GetBytes(bytes);
            a = new BigInteger(bytes);
        }
        while (a < 2 || a >= source - 2);

        BigInteger x = BigInteger.ModPow(a, d, source);
        if (x == 1 || x == source - 1)
            continue;

        for (int r = 1; r < s; r++)
        {
            x = BigInteger.ModPow(x, 2, source);
            if (x == 1)
                return false;
            if (x == source - 1)
                break;
        }

        if (x != source - 1)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private static byte[] GetBytes(BigInteger value, int size = -1)
{
    byte[] bytes = value.ToByteArray();

    if (size == -1)
    {
        size = bytes.Length;
    }

    if (bytes.Length > size + 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot squeeze value {value} to {size} bytes from {bytes.Length}.");
    }

    if (bytes.Length == size + 1 && bytes[bytes.Length - 1] != 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot squeeze value {value} to {size} bytes from {bytes.Length}.");
    }

    Array.Resize(ref bytes, size);
    Array.Reverse(bytes);
    return bytes;
}

public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    int[] hexValue = new int[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
        0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

    for (int x = 0, i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2, x += 1)
    {
        bytes[x] = (byte) (hexValue[char.ToUpper(hex[i + 0]) - '0'] << 4 | hexValue[char.ToUpper(hex[i + 1]) - '0']);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: ruslan, what BigInteger implementation are you using?  Thanks for the code!

Comment: I just realized that the original code didn't work. I updated it, but it turned out that it only works in 1/4 cases. I use standard `System.Numerics.BigInteger`

Comment: I'm still getting exceptions, probably because of my port of your code into my system.  I am using an old BigInteger from CodeProject with some different semantics.  For now, I will loop over a try-catch block until .Net gives me a key that works with exponent 3.  The speed hit is not a problem yet.

Comment: well, now I see the problem. Point is that the public exponent `e` must be chosen in such a way that the following conditions are met: `1 < e < ϕ` and `gcd(e, ϕ) = 1` where `ϕ = (p-1)(q-1)`. So when you change `e`, you need to adjust `p` and `q` as well. See https://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html#keygen for details.

Comment: I edited the code. Now it recalculates all key components.